# ImageString fontsize heigher than 5

Tags: php, gd

iam sure it's simple, but i still very beginner at this.
there is a php function called ImageString, it's the only function that i can use to convert text into images, i don't know why, but even any script (copy paste) from the php manual wont work with me.

All i want is to change the font size to something bigger than 5.

this is my code

```
header ("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
// imagecreate (x width, y width)
$img_handle = imagecreatetruecolor (800, 600) or die ("Cannot Create image"); 
// ImageColorAllocate (image, red, green, blue)
$back_color = ImageColorAllocate ($img_handle, 0, 0, 0); 
$txt_color = ImageColorAllocate ($img_handle, 243,203,146); 
imagecolortransparent($img_handle, $back_color);
$text = 'soem text goes here';
ImageString($img_handle, 40, 10,90, $text, $txt_color);
Imagejpeg ($img_handle); 
ImageDestroy($img_handle);
```

Comment: Looks like 5 is the maximum size, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php. You could try to use imagemagick.

Comment: @BotondBalázs  i think you Are right

Answer (score 1):

same technique as we do while generating a captcha image might work.

Comment: agree, but where's your code sample?

Answer (score 0):

You use capitals in the function names. Use `imagecolorallocate` instead of `ImageColorAllocate`.

Same for `ImageString`, `Imagejpeg` and `ImageDestroy`, they all need to be lowercase.

Comment: Function names in PHP are case-insensitive (pretty weird, I know).

Comment: @BotondBalázs Oh wow, that is pretty weird indeed. Learned something today.

Comment: @Sietse tried your advice, but nothing has changed.